# Is there a way to identify if an audio is VBR or CBR using FFMpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, core-audio, android-ffmpeg

I tried using FFProbe's command, but it's not enough to determine if the audio is CBR or VBR.
`ffprobe -v error -show_format -show_streams 123_1429602551009.051025.m4a`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With `ffmpeg`, I'm pretty sure it's possible, but it wouldn't be easy according to what I know. It would be cool to see if an idea I have would work, though I don't have time to check it, now. (I'll look into how it could be done (referencing [this Video StackExchange answer](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/17193/23748)). Before I do that, I'm going to suggest the use of `mediaplayer`. There's the website with [the Windows download](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download/Windows), or you can use

```
sudo apt-get install mediaplayer # Debian-type
sudo dnf install mediaplayer # RedHat-type, better command, IMHO
sudo yum install mediaplayer # RedHat-type, other command
```

As an example of using that, I have an audio which I created as a `*.wav` file - `bballdave025_tomp3.wav` . Since it's raw data in that format, it can only be a constant bitrate as a wave. I used [Audacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audacity_(audio_editor)) ([official software page](https://www.audacityteam.org/) and [github](https://github.com/audacity/audacity)) to re-encode it as a VBR MP3 file - `bballdave025_tomp3_vbr.mp3` - and a CBR MP3 file - `bballdave025_tomp3_cbr.mp3` .

```sh
$ mediainfo bballdave025_tomp3.wav | grep -i "bit rate"
Overall bit rate mode                    : Constant
Overall bit rate                         : 706 kb/s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 705.6 kb/s

$ mediainfo bballdave025_tomp3_cbr.mp3 | grep -i "bit rate"
Overall bit rate mode                    : Constant
Overall bit rate                         : 192 kb/s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 192 kb/s

$ mediainfo bballdave025_tomp3_vbr.mp3 | grep -i "bit rate"
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 101 kb/s
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 101 kb/s
Minimum bit rate                         : 32.0 kb/s
```

You can always leave off the `grep` if you want to see more information.

*Note:* If you want to figure things out for the audio part of a video containing audio, you'll need to separate the audio into its own file to use this strategy. Something like:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vn -a:c output.mp3
```

(I haven't tested that), then

```sh
mediainfo output.mp3
```

(At least I don't know any other way to do it.)

---

Idea/skeleton for doing it with `ffmpeg`

From [the source](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/17193/23748), the original idea with video was

```sh
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -an -c:v copy -segment_time 0.00001 -f segment i%0d.mp4
```

Then to run `ffprobe` on each of the segments. We'll need to change this to deal with just the audio - anyone wanting to do this would need to look into the docs to figure out the exact command needed. We can then batch our way through the `ffprobe` on each, picking out the bitrate. For one of the audio segments

```
$ ffprobe -hide_banner i01.wav
Input #0, wav, from 'i01.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:01.00, bitrate: 705 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 705 kb/s
```

So, for a group, you could parse out between `'bitrate: '` and `' kb/s'`, then run `sort -u` on it. If you get more than one number, you have a variable bit rate. (At least that's an idea, which would need fleshing out by an interested person.)

Comment: "Audacity to re-encode", weird from you.

Comment: hahaha. Nice, @tripulse. I'll make it clearer that Audacity is a program by including a link to the download page.

Comment: Not that, I mean why couldn't you just re-encode it using FFmpeg?

Comment: That's also a good point. @tripulse. I'm not sure why I used Audacity, other than that I'd done some variable-bit-rate encoding using it previously, and I hadn't done it using FFMPEG at that time.